# Stereo Webcam Depth Detection

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I'm newbie to computer vision.
I'm trying to calculate depth from stereo webcam.
I flowed this steps:

- Camera calibration:Calibrate each camera individually,i got Rms 0.2 and 0.18 then i calibrate both cameras (Rms:0.8) using openCv3.
- Calculate Disparity map using  ximgproc and opencv3 (create left matcher the right matcher and then createDisparityWLSFilter)
- detect and object (using colors)
- Use this equation: depth=base_line*focal_length/disparity to get depth
  I got strange values,i even tried to used cv2.reprojectImageTo3D but it gave same problem.

I cannot have fix values. when the ball is farther the depth is smaller.
I didn't understand the (x,y,z) given from the 3D reconstitution
here is my code.
Please help

## code

while(True):
    if not (left.grab() and right.grab()):
        print("No more frames")
        break
    _, leftFrame = left.retrieve()
    _, rightFrame = right.retrieve()
    leftFrame = cv2.remap(leftFrame,leftMapX,leftMapY,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    rightFrame = 
    cv2.remap(rightFrame,rightMapX,rightMapY,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

```
displ = left_matcher.compute(rightFrame,leftFrame).astype(np.float32)/16
dispr = right_matcher.compute(leftFrame ,rightFrame ).astype(np.float32)/16
displ = np.int16(displ)
dispr = np.int16(dispr)
filteredImg=None
filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, rightFrame, None, dispr)  # important to put "imgL" here!!!
filteredImg = cv2.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)
cv2.imshow('disparity', filteredImg)

center=bd.ball_detection(rightFrame)

points_3D = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(filteredImg, Q)
if center!= None:
    x= points_3D[center][0]
    y= points_3D[center][1]
    z= points_3D[center][2]
    print("1",triangulation_constant/filteredImg[center])
    print("2",x,y,z)
```